# Displaying Flows in Menu Items - Override Issue

Tags: community, visual-workflow, customer-community, partner-communities

My Scenario : I'm trying to implement the flows into the communities. Below Steps were followed:

1. Create a Menu Label --> select a 'Site Page' from Type --> select 'Flow' from Page --> provided URL of Flow in URL.[image]

**Issue:** When i repeat the steps for the second Menu item and includes a new flow, the Flow in 1st tab is also getting updated and vice versa with second tab.
It looks like only one Site Page and One Flow is allowed per community. Is it a limitation in salesforce or anything i'm missing.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This does not seems like limitation because I tried to implement the same in my personal developer org and it is working as expected. I was able to add two different flows for two menus and working as expected. Can you confirm which template you are using for community?

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala Template type is 'Partner Central'. Will it make a difference?

Comment: I don't hope so . Just want to check it because I was able to achieve it in my personal org. Did you try it in some other personal org?

Comment: I have checked with that template as well and it is working as expected. Can you check in some other org to confirm if it is issue specific to that Org.